# Date filters fail in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a function:

```
def update_coins_table():
    # Check if the currency has been updated in the last hour
    up_to_date_currency = Currency.objects.filter(
        currency_value_in_dollars_date=
        [datetime.now(), timedelta(hours=1)]).order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:len(coins_ids)]

    if up_to_date_currency.exists():
        # Return if it is
        return

    if not do_greeting():
        print("Gecko crypto board not reachable. Db setup")
        return

    crypto_coins_prices = cg.get_price(ids=coins_ids_str, vs_currencies='usd')
    datetime_now = datetime.now()
    for coin_key in crypto_coins_prices:
        coin = Currency(
            currency_name=coin_key,
            currency_value_in_dollars=crypto_coins_prices[coin_key]['usd'],
            currency_value_in_dollars_date=datetime_now)
        coin.save()
```

and get the following error on executing filter(),

```
up_to_date_currency = Currency.objects.filter(
        currency_value_in_dollars_date=
        [datetime.now(), timedelta(hours=1)]).order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:len(coins_ids)]
```

Error message:

```
Internal Server Error: /get_currency/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\crypto\manage_crypto_currency\views.py", line 21, in get_latest_currency
    update_coins_table()
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\crypto\manage_crypto_currency\get_coins_scheduler.py", line 38, in update_coins_table
    up_to_date_currency = Currency.objects.filter(
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1319, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 76, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1357, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1217, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1318, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 107, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
[22/Nov/2020 20:27:44] "GET /get_currency/ HTTP/1.1" 500 142548
```

The model of 'Currency' is:

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    currency_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    currency_value_in_dollars = models.FloatField()
    currency_value_in_dollars_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.currency_name
```

Why can't I filter by 'currency_value_in_dollars_date'? check if the currency value has been updated within the last hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not simply uses a list of two values to filter. If you for example want to retrieve all elements in between you can work with a [**`__range`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

current_time = now()

up_to_date_currency = Currency.objects.filter(
    currency_value_in_dollars_date__range=(
        current_time-timedelta(hours=1),
        current_time
    )
).order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:len(coins_ids)]
```

This will thus retrieve all `Currency` objects between an hour ago and now.

Answer (score 2):

If by

> check if the currency value has been updated within the last hour

you mean you want to filter all rows up to 1 hour ago, then replace

```
currency_value_in_dollars_date=
        [datetime.now(), timedelta(hours=1)]
```

with (notice [`__gte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt))

```
currency_value_in_dollars_date__gte=datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
```

If you want to filter by array, then you'd have to either use `JSONField` to match value, or use `__in` to execute SQL `in`. Otherwise, you can't filter by array, so what you did is basically invalid.

Depending on your settings, you should probably use `timezone.now()` from django instead of `datetime`.